# How to check if collapsed navbar is opened or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar and on mobile it collapses. I want to know when the navbar is opened and when it's closed.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to check the state of the .collapse class

```
var isVisible = $( ".collapse" ).is( ":visible" );

var isHidden = $( ".collapse" ).is( ":hidden" );
```

and now check this variables .